# How to set system.web compilation debug mode off via VSTS

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I have this web.config file with the compilation option set as below:

```
<configuration>
...
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

How to turn off the compilation's debug flag to false via VSTS's Build Definitions?

---

Update:
I'm deploying the system to Azure server by VSTS's release function.

Comment: Why don't you use transformation? Web.config has transformation functionality which can be used to change the value.

Comment: [Here's the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) to the comment by @Justcode above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use transformation to achieve what you want.
here is the documenation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

Here is how your Web.debug.config file should look. You can also use web.release.config if you want to use transform in release mode.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For more information on using Web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301874 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--
    In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of
    "connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator
    finds an atrribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB"
        connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  -->

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false"   xdt:Transform="Replace"/>         

    <!--
      In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire
      <customErrors> section of your Web.config file.
      Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the
      <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
    -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You also could refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution#xml-transformation

Comment: @JoeyCai Thanks for that.